# object is not a function - Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the error message I am getting for:

```
(function($){
    var dataObject = {
        class : 'someClass',
        method : 'someClassMethod',
        data : { someData : 'example' }
    }

    (new AA.Aisis_Ajax(data_object, 'POST')).init();

})(jQuery)
```

pertains to:

```
    var dataObject = {
        class : 'someClass',
        method : 'someClassMethod',
        data : { someData : 'example' }
    }
```

(If that's deleted the code works...)

The issue is that this returns `object is not a function`. well duh, I am trying to create a object that's passed to the class `Aisis_Ajax`

What is going on here?

Comment: `class` is a [reserved word in ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#In_ECMAScript_5), you better use something else, e.g. `className`.

Comment: @Pavlo: It doesn't hurt but it's not an error. Any identifier is a valid property name in an object literal, which includes reserved keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your object declaration is immediately followed by parenthesis, so the parser thinks you're trying to call a function.

Try putting a semicolon at the end of your object declaration:

```
var dataObject = {
    class : 'someClass',
    method : 'someClassMethod',
    data : { someData : 'example' }
}; // <---
```

Comment: Omitting the parenthesis should works as well (`new AA.Aisis_Ajax(data_object, 'POST').init()`) but readability suffers IMO.